# How to pass a parameter to a dynamically set JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I have one JavaScript that creates rows in a table like this:

```
  function AddRow(text,rowID) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblNotePanel');
    var row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);

    var cell = row.insertCell();
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    cell.id = rowID;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "gold";

    cell.onclick = clickTest;
    
    cell.appendChild(textNode);
  }
```

In the above function, I set the cell's `onclick` function to call another JavaScript function called `clickTest`.  My question is when I assign the `onclick` event to call `clickTest`, how do I set parameter information to be sent when the `clickTest` method is called on the cell's `onclick` event?  Or, how do I access the cell's ID in the `clickTest` function?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.onclick = function() { clickTest(rowID); };
```

The idea is that you are binding the onclick handler to the anonymous function.  The anonymous function calls clickTest with rowID as the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

In the clickTest function you should have access to a the `this` variable.  Try this inside of `clickTest` function:

```
alert(this.id);
```

This will refer to the DOM element that fired the event.

Basically, there isn't really a way to pass parameters to an event handler function.  The reason for that is that the browser is executing the function based on an event and you are not actually calling the function.

You can use closures which allow you to access local variables (to the closure) when you assign the event handler function.  That would look like this:

```
cell.onclick = function() { alert(this.id); alert(cell.id); };
```

Were `cell.id` is the locally scoped variable that is still considered in scope when the event handler is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solutions work most of the time except for special scenarios.

In case you have a for loop adding `onclick`s calling another function with different parameters and when testing you realize all your item's behave like the last item, you may consider adding `onclick` as a text:

```
for(var loopObj of loopObjList)
    mydiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript: pick_option(' + loopObj.id + ', "' + loopObj.value + '");' );
```